# How to contribute to open source project in Java on GitHub

Tags: java, github, open-source

I would like to contribute to an Open Source project in Java, can anyone suggest me a open source project which is in Java?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[See the trending Java projects on GitHub](https://github.com/trending?l=java). Pull, study, see the issues then contribute.

Comment: Once you find a project you want to work with you can start by triaging issues which helps you get familiar with the project without requiring a huge commitment you can use https://codetriage.com